# How to merge changes from master and then commit merged changes to master?

Tags: git

When I perform : `git branch` I receive :

```
* feature/my-feature
  master
```

So my current branch is `feature/my-feature`

I've made changes and committed these changes to branch `feature/my-feature`. I can view diffs between `master` and `feature/my-feature` using `git diff master feature/my-feature` but when I attempt to merge my changes from `master` to `feature/my-feature` using command : `git merge master` I receive message : `Already up-to-date.`

How to merge changes from master to my feature branch and then commit merged changes to master ?

Comment: if you want to changes from master to my-feature branch, try git cherry-pick.

Comment: I always use `git pull origin/master` or `git pull master` if my local master up to date and than `git push`

Comment: Are you sure there are commits in `master` that are not in `feature/my-feature`? That is, have the branches diverged?

Comment: You're probably running into the usual Git-newbie issue that `git merge` is inherently confusing (which it is, especially if you have used any other version-control system or source-code-management system and are familiar with *their* merge commands). It might help to include, in your question, the output of `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` (or enough of it to identify both branch tips).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message tells you that `master` currently exists in your `feature/my-feature` ancestry. And as such there is nothing to do. See the [git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_pre_merge_checks) documentation for more details

You probably want to merge with `origin/master` instead, since that is a more up-to-date state of the `master` branch.

So I would try the following:

1. `git fetch origin`
2. `git merge origin/master`